# Find the perimeter of a triangle

Tags: geometry

$DE \parallel AB,\,$ $AF$ and $BF$ are bisectors of $\angle A\;\text{and} \;\angle B$ respectively, and $AC = 8,\;BC = 12.$
[image]

How do I find the perimeter of triangle CDE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angle BAF is equal to FAD (AF bisector of angle A). Since DE is parallel to AB, angle BAF is equal to AFD. Therefore AFD triangle is isosceles. FD=AD. Similarly, you can prove that FE=EB. The perimeter of CDE is CD+DE+EC=CD+DF+FE+EC=CD+DA+BE+EC=AC+BC=8+12=20

Answer (score 0):

Since $FE\parallel AB$, we have $\widehat{EFB}=\widehat{FBA}=\widehat{FBE}$, hence $FEB$ is an isosceles triangle with $FE=EB$. Similarly, we have $FD=DA$, hence:

$$\begin{eqnarray*} CD+CE+DE &=& (CD+DF)+(CE+EF)\\ &=& (CD+DA)+(CE+EB)\\ &=& AC+BC = \color{red}{20}.\end{eqnarray*}$$